# Singleton class with @Startup annotation WL 11g

Tags: web-services, log4j, weblogic

i have a problem deploying my webservice to Weblogic 11g.

JAVA: JRockit 1.6.x

I need to run a method on webservice deployment and i made this code:

```java
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupBean {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StartupBean.class);

@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
   logger.error("WS started.");

}

@PreDestroy
private void preDestroy() {
    logger.error("WS stoped.");
}
}
```

without any additional xml config.

It works normally on 12c but i need it on 11g.

What is the workaround?

Thanks

Comment: workaround for this functionality with ejb 3.0 on WL11g.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this in pre-3.1-EJB without XML config.

The common practice in EJB 3.0 for implementing a `@Startup` bean was to instantiate in in a servlet, which is configured to load on startup in `web.xml`. If you need it just for log4j you can initialize it directly from such servlet.